# LyX footnotes do not create footnotes, only text in body

Tags: lyx, footnotes

Ever since I updated my MacBook Air to Yosemite (very late -- just this week), LyX has been malfunctioning in its footnote functionality.
I did a fresh install of both TeX and LyX, but the issue persists. Here's what LyX looks like:

[image]

---

Here's the PDF output (pdflatex):

[image]

---

Here's the TeX file output (pdflatex):

[image]

When I enter "ugly red code" and type in `\footnote{...}`, though, the footnote DOES appear. So it seems that just LyX's footnote tool is broken.
Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I installed an older version of LyX (2.1.2.2) to overwrite the most current version on my computer. Now footnotes work just as planned. Reinstalling the newest version reintroduces the problem, so I'll just stick with the previous version...

Comment: I can't replicate this result (using LyX 2.1.3 on Windows).

Comment: ...this might be OS-specific. As mentioned, it works for me on Windows. This may be worth filing on the [LyX bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome).

Comment: I don't see this on Linux either. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the Footnote inset got redefined. Can you please backup your LyX user folder (help > about for its location). Then, with LyX exited, delete it. Then restart LyX. Then try again. Does it work now? If it does work, please keep the old user directory, I would like to take a look at it. If it does not work, then as Werner suggested consider filing a bug report. We have not had any reports of this before.

Comment: Thanks, Werner and scottkosty. I have done what scottkosty suggested -- reinstalling the newest version, which reintroduced the problem, making a copy of the user folder, then deleting it and opening LyX, which created a new user folder. Voila, problem is gone. What should I do with the folder I saved? Where should I send it? I'm new to StackExchange, since I've never before had a problem like this I couldn't solve. Thanks!

Comment: @scottkosty See the above comment.

Comment: @JohnSearle Thanks for being willing to help us fix whatever bug you found. Does your folder have anything that you wish to have kept private in it (for example in the 'preferences' file it lists your user name)? If not, please send an email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org with your folder attached (in a compressed file), describing the problem and how you fixed the problem, and linking to this thread. Also, please attach your *new* user directory (the one that works). If there is something private in the folders, please send instead the email to me at skostysh@lyx.org.

Comment: @JohnSearle Whenever you comment and you want someone to be notified of your comment, you should use `@` followed by their user name. If TorbjørnT. had not notified me, I would have never seen your comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a corrupt user directory.

Comment: @JohnSearle can you please send me the files? Or preferably can you post them at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9653 ? This will help us solve the bug.